# Filtering a table by different properties id, value in another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have this structure of data

**TABLE_MAIN**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | object 1 |
| 2 | object 2 |

**TABLE_COMPL_DATA**

| ID | ID_MAIN | ID_TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 'house' |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | '2' |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | '1' |
| 1 | 2 | 7 | '2' |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | '1' |

I want to extract all the registers from main table, with their properties with all the conditions covered:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.name, 

FROM MAIN m
INNER JOIN TABLE_COMPL_DATA cd on m.id = cd.id_main

WHERE
 cd.id_type in (5,7,3)

AND (cd.id_type = 5 and cd.value = 'house')
AND (cd.id_type = 7 and cd.value = '2')
```

I want this query shows 3 rows from the main object from ID 1 with their 3 properties (2 of these properties must have values `5=>'house'` and `7=>'2'`, the other `id_type` property can be any value)

Problem is that when the two `AND` conditions are overlapping, the query doesn't return any results. I am sure there are methods to make this type of filters but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need `OR`s instead of `AND`s, like so:

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.name
FROM   main m
INNER  JOIN table_compl_data cd
ON     m.id = cd.id_main
WHERE  cd.id_type = 3
OR     (cd.id_type = 5 AND cd.value = 'house')
OR     (cd.id_type = 7 AND cd.value = '2');
```

---

If I understand your comment correctly, you're asking for objects that have rows that meet each of those three conditions, therefore you're after something like:

```
WITH    table_main AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'object 1' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 2 ID, 'object 2' NAME FROM dual),
  table_compl_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 1 id_main, 5 id_type, 'house' VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 2 ID, 1 id_main, 7 id_type, '2' VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 3 ID, 1 id_main, 3 id_type, '1' VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 4 ID, 2 id_main, 7 id_type, '2' VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 5 ID, 2 id_main, 3 id_type, '1' VALUE FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables
SELECT m.id,
       m.name
FROM   table_main m
INNER  JOIN (SELECT id_main,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT id_type)
             FROM   table_compl_data
             WHERE  id_type = 3
             OR     (id_type = 5 AND value = 'house')
             OR     (id_type = 7 AND value = '2')
             GROUP BY id_main
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_type) = 3) cd
ON     m.id = cd.id_main;

        ID NAME
---------- --------
         1 object 1
```

I wasn't sure if you could have multiple rows per id_type in your table_compl_data, so I added a `distinct` to the `count`. If there's a unique constraint preventing that, or you want to check for objects that only have 1 row per id_type and ignore ones that have multiple rows (e.g. if there were two or more id_type = 3 rows with different values), then you would remove the `distinct`.

Comment: i need exactly that have 5-'house' or 7-'2', It can't have only 5-'house' by example

Comment: Ah, you want to show objects that have 3 rows, one with id_type = 3, one with id_type = 5, value = 'house', and one with id_type = 7 and value = 2?

Comment: yep, this conditions will be builded in dynamic way and must to have all

Comment: Yep! just like these. I was trying some combinations of the group by  but not this way! Thanks for the help Boneist